# Linq to object Group Join Overflow exception

Tags: c#, performance, linq

I had 4 Object

```
public class DataInfo
{
    public int BannerId { get; set; }
    public int AdsType { get; set; }

    public int SiteId { get; set; }
    public int MngSiteId { get; set; }
    public string SiteName { get; set; }

    public int PositionId { get; set; }
    public int MngPositionId { get; set; }
    public string PositionName { get; set; }

    public int MngCategoryId { get; set; }
    public int CategoryId { get; set; }
    public string CategoryName { get; set; }

    public DateTime LogDate { get; set; }

    public double Impression { get; set; }
    public double Click { get; set; }
    public double CTR { get; set; }
}

public class ZoneInfo
{
    public int MngSiteId { get; set; }
    public int SiteId { get; set; }
    public string SiteName { get; set; }

    public int MngPositionId { get; set; }
    public int PositionId { get; set; }
    public string PositionName { get; set; }

    public int MngCategoryId { get; set; }
    public int CategoryId { get; set; }
    public string CategoryName { get; set; }

    public int AdsSale { get; set; }

}

public class LogTotalInfo
{
    public int TotalId { get; set; }
    public DateTime LogDate { get; set; }
    public double Click { get; set; }
    public double Action { get; set; }
    public double Impression { get; set; }
    public int AdsType { get; set; }
    public int SiteId { get; set; }
    public int PositionId { get; set; }
    public int CategoryId { get; set; }
    public int BannerId { get; set; }
    public double Visitor { get; set; }
    public double UniqueClick { get; set; }
}

public class ProductInfo
{
    public int ProductId { get; set; }
    public int BannerId { get; set; }
    public int LabelId { get; set; }
    public int ProductType { get; set; }
    public string BannerName { get; set; }
    public string LabelName { get; set; }
}
```

and I join using linq

```
List<DataInfo> di = (from t in tTotal // LogTotalInfo
                    join p in tProduct // ProductInfo
                    on t.BannerId equals p.BannerId
                    join z in tZone // ZoneInfo
                    on new { t.SiteId, t.CategoryId, t.PositionId } equals new { z.SiteId, z.CategoryId, z.PositionId }
                    group new { t, p, z } by new { z.MngSiteId, z.MngCategoryId, z.MngPositionId, z.PositionName, z.SiteName, z.CategoryName, t.AdsType, t.LogDate } into cg2
                    select new DataInfo
                    {
                        LogDate = cg2.Key.LogDate,
                        MngSiteId = cg2.Key.MngSiteId,
                        MngCategoryId = cg2.Key.MngCategoryId,
                        MngPositionId = cg2.Key.MngPositionId,
                        PositionName = cg2.Key.PositionName,
                        SiteName = cg2.Key.SiteName,
                        CategoryName = cg2.Key.CategoryName,
                        AdsType = cg2.Key.AdsType,
                        Impression = cg2.Sum(x => x.t.Impression),
                        Click = cg2.Sum(x => x.t.Click)
                    }).ToList();
```

And it throw overflow exception at `group new { t, p, z }`.
The `tZone` ~ 10k records, the `tTotal` ~ 2m records and the `tProduct` ~ 65k records.
 How can I join without being exception or any other way to get the same result

Comment: Note that what you have is not a _groupjoin_ but rather a join followed by a _groupby_.

Comment: One of the primary principles of LINQ is laziness. Items are produced as they are requested. However, by calling `ToList` you materialize the entire query into a single in memory collection. LINQ can actually be used to represent arbitrarily or infinitely long sequences but for such a scenario to work you must not attempt to materialize the all  values prior to consumption.

Comment: You're trying to join these in memory, or via an EF provider?

Comment: @AustinDrenski i'm trying to join these in memory

Comment: @AluanHaddad how can i change this into group join to make it faster / not throw exception

Comment: Don't try to make it faster, try to make it not explode. Simply write `IEnumerable<DataInfo> = ...` and remove the `.ToList()`. Then use a `foreach` loop to access the results.

Comment: Actually, it could well be `IQueryable<DataInfo>`. Depends on the source which I cannot see. You can also write `var di = ...` to have the precise type inferred.

Comment: You need to think about what you're trying to create. Split this up into a couple of steps, materializing at each stage. That will point to which of your joins is pushing you past the indexing limit.